# Rails logs. what does this mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I get This on my development log. What does the mCACHE lines mean? Are they SQL queries?

```
 ←[1m←[36mTodo Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE ("todos".project_id IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mLog Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE ("logs".todo_id IN (134,135,136))
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 3) LIMIT 1
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 3) LIMIT 1←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 3) LIMIT 1
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1←[0m
 ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
 ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE ("firms"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1←[0m
```

Comment: You can use the "-r" switch to less if that's what you're using to see your logs. "less -r development.log", this will correctly interpret ANSI codes and make things look nice.

Comment: The output to the log is expected to be `cat`'d or `tail -f`'d to the screen where the terminal can interpret the codes. If you use an editor, or `less` without `-r`, you'll get the uuuuu-gly output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache means that you've already run the same query and it's result is stored in memory, so the query isn't actually run against the database. They are all queries, it's what Active Record actually does when it talks to the database.

Answer (score 4):

The `[numberm` are just [ANSI color codes](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html) - it's supposed to show pretty colors in a smart terminal, looks bad otherwise.

The `CACHE` is "an sql query, cached (executed previously, now loaded from cache)" - see e.g. [this](http://www.dx13.co.uk/articles/2008/02/06/Ruby-on-Rails-ActiveRecord-Query-Caching.html)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any smart terminals for windows?

Comment: Well, probably the best known is PuTTY - a SSH client/terminal emulator: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html (not useful as a local console though). Also, what @rwilliams said.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I'll check'em out.

Comment: +1 for Putty, the multipurpose tool. It slices and dices too.

Answer (score 3):

That is the evidence that Rails SQL Caching is working:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching